# How to use LockModeType.NONE with hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, playframework, locking

I have been trying to set the lock type to none for some of the queries running on frequently updated tables but I keep getting Locking errors in SQL Server.

```
public static List<Ticket> findOpen() {
    Query query = SNMPTicket.em().createQuery("from Ticket where endTime is null", Ticket.class);
    query.setLockMode(LockModeType.NONE);
    List<Ticket> tickets = query.getResultList();
    return tickets;
}
```

> play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute
>   query     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)    at
>   Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute
>   query     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)    at
>   models.gasper.snmp.Ticket.findOpen(Ticket.java:337)   at
>   controllers.Tickets.show(Tickets.java:261)

Is this the correct way to generate a no lock hint with hibernate or am I missing something?

Comment: That's beside the point. In my scenario it make sense and is the easiest solution.

Comment: No. It's not beside the point. But you go ahead. Reap what you sow.

Comment: Humm, that doesn't sound very constructive to me... My jobs run every minutes and update statistics which do not need bullet proof accuracy. Perhaps you could help with suggesting a better solution instead?

Comment: "My jobs run every minutes and update statistics which do not need bullet proof accuracy" - why would you be doing that? Very large table with lots of inserts?

Comment: The system we use is event based and those events are generated with a high frequency and persisted on that table.